# UITableView displays last item from array in every cell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, struct

I'm using an array of instances of the same struct to populate a tableview and I'm stumped by the last item in the array displaying in every cell.

```
class RoutesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var routesTableView: UITableView!


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return type1UnownedRoutesArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let routeCell = routesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "routeCell") as! RouteTableViewCell



    for Flight in type1UnownedRoutesArray {
        routeCell.originLabel.text = "Origin:          \(Flight.origin)"
        routeCell.destinationLabel.text = "Destination: \(Flight.destination)"
        routeCell.priceLabel.text = "Price: $\(Flight.popularity)"
    }
  return routeCell
}
```

And the struct itself:

```
struct Flight {

var origin: String
var destination: String
var mileage: Int
var popularity: Int
var isOwned: Bool

}
```

If I add `[indexPath.row]` after `for Flight in type1UnownedRoutesArray` I get `Type Flight does not conform to protocol Sequence`

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your issue is this one in your `cellForRow` method, you are cycling over all your flights objects in your array, and of course the last value is keeping in your cell, so you need replace **this**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let routeCell = routesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "routeCell") as! RouteTableViewCell

    for Flight in type1UnownedRoutesArray {
        routeCell.originLabel.text = "Origin:          \(Flight.origin)"
        routeCell.destinationLabel.text = "Destination: \(Flight.destination)"
        routeCell.priceLabel.text = "Price: $\(Flight.popularity)"
    }
  return routeCell
}
```

**By this**

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let routeCell = routesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "routeCell") as! RouteTableViewCell

    let flight = type1UnownedRoutesArray[indexPath.row]
    routeCell.originLabel.text = "Origin:          \(flight.origin)"
    routeCell.destinationLabel.text = "Destination: \(flight.destination)"
    routeCell.priceLabel.text = "Price: $\(flight.popularity)"
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Why `if let`? That won't compile because `type1UnownedRoutesArray[indexPath.row]` does not return an optional. If the index is out of range the code will crash, not return `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't test that, thanks as always, my answer was updated

Comment: @rmaddy did you use guard to ensure that your indexPath.row is not out of range? can you check my answer?

Comment: I wouldn't use `guard`. You want the app to crash if the index path is out of range because that means there is a serious bug in the code and it needs to be fixed.

Comment: It will crash without the `guard` and without the `assert` so adding them is redundant.

Comment: ok so is better let them crash. I got your point thanks @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you should not be iterating your flights array inside the cellforrow method as it is called once per item in your array.

try this instead

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let routeCell = routesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "routeCell") as! RouteTableViewCell

    let flight = type1UnownedRoutesArray[indexPath.row]
    routeCell.originLabel.text = "Origin:          \(flight.origin)"
    routeCell.destinationLabel.text = "Destination: \(flight.destination)"
    routeCell.priceLabel.text = "Price: $\(flight.popularity)"

  return routeCell
}
```